# select first three values order by a column

Tags: mysql, select, limit

i have 2 tables :

med

```
CREATE TABLE med 
(id_med INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name_m VARCHAR(50),
surname_m VARCHAR(50),
spec VARCHAR(50),
UNIQUE (surname_m,name_m));
```

viz

```
CREATE TABLE viz
(id_m INT NOT NULL,
id_p INT  NOT NULL,
id_c INT  NOT NULL,
dt DATETIME)
```

i need to select the first 3 values for the fullname and count(id_p) for each spec.
the following query gives me the first value but i just cant see what to do next.

```
  (SELECT distinct(concat(name_m,' ',surname_m)) AS fullname, COUNT(id_p) as no, (select distinct(spec))
    FROM med m JOIN viz v ON m.id_med = v.id_m
    WHERE year(dt)=2005
    GROUP BY spec
    ORDER BY spec;
```

any answer will be highly appreciated. thank you.

the result should be like this :

```
  fullname       count(id_p)          spec
    name1              1000            a
    name2               900            a
    name3               890            a
    name4              2000            b
    name5               600            b
    name6               200            b
    name7               100            c
    name8                60            c
    name9                59            c
```

....

my current result shows:

```
    fullname       count(id_p)        spec
    name1              1000            a
    name4              2000            b
    name7               100            c
```

Comment: Can you fill in the tables with data and give an example of what you want your query to return.

Comment: so now what is your result is showing according to your current query?

Comment: What does your original data look like?

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that returns the first three values of the `spec` column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(name_m, ' ', 'surname_m) AS fullname, COUNT(id_p) AS no, m1.spec
FROM med AS m1
JOIN viz AS v ON m1.id_med = v.id_m
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT spec
      FROM med
      ORDER BY spec
      LIMIT 3) AS m2 ON m1.spec = m2.spec
WHERE YEAR(v1.dt) = 2005
GROUP BY fullname, m1.spec
ORDER BY fullname, m1.spec
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. it's not working because `spec` is from med table not viz.

Comment: Oops, I got confused. Try it now.

Comment: Now it gives error code 1052. column `spec` in field list is ambiguous. I think this could be done with union. I'll keep reading and come back with an answer.

Comment: I had `v1.spec` it should have been `m1.spec`.

Comment: Still not a good result but I think I got something to work with. Your code returns all records for 3 specs. I need to return top 3 records for each spec. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Oh, I completely misunderstood the question.